# How do I keep my Android testing libraries separate from my application libraries in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, integration-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I have my module dependencies set up like so in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies
{
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
   androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs/test', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Inside my libs folder I have all the libraries necessary to building my application. I placed the libraries necessary to running tests in a subfolder called "test"

This seems to work as my code compiles, and I can make my module. When I attempt to run any of my tests, however, it fails to find the test libraries I attempted to include. The errors in the Gradle console actually point back to pieces of my code that don't show any errors.

Also, I do have my tests set up correctly, because I can get them to run by moving the required jars into the libs folder and changing my dependencies to:

```
dependencies
{
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

But then I don't really see the point of androidTestCompile if it's not working. I'd also rather not include these jar files in my apk if I don't have to.

If it helps, I'm using Android studio version 1.2.2 and Gradle plugin version 1.2.3.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you running unit tests, or connected Android tests (those that require an Android device or emulator)?

Comment: what is the import statement you are using to reference the test jars?

Comment: I'm running connected Android tests.

One of the imports in my test code looks like 
      "import com.robotium.solo.Solo;"
and the robotium jar file is in the libs/test directory.

Comment: "it fails to find the test libraries I attempted to include" -- what is your specific symptom? If you move these from `libs/test/` to `libsTest/` (or anything else *outside* of `libs/`), does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See below example.

create ***tests folder*** parallel to **src** folder.
create all test cases into that folder.
if you create folder into another path you need to make call for this.(Added into code.)

```
 dependencies {
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/org.mockito:mockito-core:3.9.5')
    androidTestompile files('espresso-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bundled.jar')
    }

defaultConfig {

    testApplicationId "xxx.xx.abc"
    testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']

    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    instrumentTest {

        java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }

    androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
```

Comment: Thanks! I think my issue was that I had the default setup of androidTest in src/androidTest, but I had my main source directory as just 'src'. I'm assuming there must have been a conflict there. This seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sourceSets to keep your apk free from the test librarys
[Gradle User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing-Android-Libraries)
Use the 'main' one for your production code and the 'androidTest' one for the tests, gradle then automatically adds the specified sources.

```
   sourceSets {
        main {
            ...
        }
        androidTest {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to build my apk outside of Android Studio to keep these separate still? It seems like when I load my debug apk it still loads the testing libraries. Thanks for the help so far.